# Port 8731 works internally, not externally. Win 7 + XAMPP

Tags: router, port, port-forwarding, xampp, web-services

I have a web service which needs to run on port `8731`. I'm running Windows 7 x64 with XAMPP.

For privacy sake, let's assume my public facing IP, seen on whatismyip.com, is **123.456.78.90**:

- **http://192.168.0.2** // Works fine, loads the first `<VirtualHost *:80>` block in my vhosts
- **http://192.168.0.2:8731/WebService/Namespace** // Works fine, returns the wsdl
- **http://123.456.78.90** // Works fine, points to `192.168.0.2`
- **http://123.456.78.90:8731/WebService/Namespace** // Fails. Chrome cannot connect to 123.456.78.90:8731

In my router, I have port forwarding setup. Port 80 routes to `192.168.0.2`. I tried forwarding port 8731 to the same IP but it doesn't seem to make a difference. The port doesn't appear to be blocked by my router at all.

A test on [canyouseeme.org](http://www.canyouseeme.org) yields a Success for port 80 and a Timeout for port 8731.

I also tried adding `NameVirtualHost *:8731` to my vhosts and setting a `<VirtualHost *:8731>` block after enabling port forwarding for port 8731 to 192.168.0.2, and adding a `Listen 8731` line in my httpd.conf, and it points to the correct vhost block.

Any ideas? Where can I look next?

Comment: Can you check for blockings in windows firewall itself? Maybe Windows firewall blocking it.

Comment: *Slams head into wall. That was it. Just needed to tell the firewall to open that port specifically. Apache was in there allowed on all ports but I forgot this isn't apache. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: Edited the comment to make it more general answer: Firewall issue ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure any firewall isn't blocking that specific port along the way. Can you check for blockings in windows firewall itself? Maybe Windows firewall blocking it.